# Is there a symmetric positive definite matrix $P$ such that $PA$ is diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be nonsingular. Can we show that there exists a symmetric positive definite matrix $P\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $PA$ is a diagonal matrix? If not, can we come up with some conditions on $A$ that guarantees the existence of $P$?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose such a matrix exists. Then $Q = P^{-1}$ is also positive definite symmetric, and $A = QD,$ so $A_{ij} = Q_{ij} d_j,$ and so $A_{ij}/A_{ji} = d_j/d_i.$ Since the RHS has ratios only, we can normalize by setting $d_1=1,$ and so we recover the other $d$s, namely $d_j = A_{1j}/A_{j1}.$ From here you can figure out the consistency conditions.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a rigorous proof. I don't think I can conclude from your answer that some conditions must be satisfied for the existence of $P$.

Comment: @Mohkam7 What exactly does "I need a rigorous proof" mean? Having $n^2/2$ equations and $n$ unknowns is not evidence enough?

Comment: I still cannot see how this proof works. You mentioned we have n unknowns but I cannot see it. Also, I am not sure how to formulate positive definiteness of $P$ as equations. Any help is appreciated. Thanks